# Domain specific language to describe ensemble model

Tags: machine-learning, training, ensemble-modeling, ensemble

I'm looking for some tool/library/widely used approach to describe Hierarchical Model structure like ensemble:
[image: example hierarchical model]

It's absolutely straightforward how to do it with simple ensemble like 
[image: simple ensemble]

It can be explained even in yml format like this:

```
code: "cats"
models:
  - code: "siamese"
  - code: "persian"
  - code: "sphynx"
```

It's obvious from code that execute simple ensemble model that leaves should go first and parent model aggregates their results.

But it's looks difficult to describe in the same way hierarchical model because it's executed in inverse direction. Probably, someone can suggest approach how to do it?